# Why does ListPlot not work out of the box with a list of associations and how to get it to work?

Tags: plotting, associations, version-13.3

Let us assume I have several sets of data points with labels, e.g.:

```
alabels = Array["a" ~~ ToString[#] &, 10];
blabels = Array["b" ~~ ToString[#] &, 10];
avalues = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1], {10, 2}];
bvalues = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[11, 1], {10, 2}];
aassoc = AssociationThread[alabels -> avalues];
bassoc = AssociationThread[blabels -> bvalues];
```

Assuming the above,
`ListPlot[aassoc]` works, as does `ListPlot[bassoc]`, while `ListPlot[{aassoc, bassoc}]` yields a `Callout:copos: {Automatic} is not a valid position for the placement of callouts.` error message. Firstly, I'd like to know why the latter does not work, and secondly, how to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: `Show[ListPlot /@ {aassoc, bassoc}, PlotRange -> All]`

Answer (score 5):

Building up on Bob Hanlon's comment:

```
alabels = Array["a" ~~ ToString[#] &, 10];
blabels = Array["b" ~~ ToString[#] &, 10];
avalues = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1], {10, 2}];
bvalues = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[11, 1], {10, 2}];
aassoc = AssociationThread[alabels -> avalues];
bassoc = AssociationThread[blabels -> bvalues];

center = {Values@aassoc, Values@bassoc} // Map[Mean] // Mean
MapThread[
  ListPlot[#1, PlotStyle -> #2, Background -> None] &, {{aassoc, 
    bassoc}, {Red, Blue}}] //
 Show[#, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> center] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, `ListPlot` cannot handle list of associations in the first argument. Using the option `LabelingFunction -> None`, we suppress the call to `Callout`  and avoid the error message. In this case, only the first association is rendered:

```
ListPlot[{aassoc, bassoc}, LabelingFunction -> None]
```

[image]

#### Work-arounds

#### 1. Pre-process input associations into a single association

Wrap values of each association with desired `Style` and `Join` to get a single association:

```
abassoc = Apply[Join]@
  MapThread[{x, y} |-> Map[Style[#, y] &] @ x] @
  {{aassoc, bassoc}, {Red, Blue}}; 

 ListPlot[abassoc, 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"A", "B"}]]
```

[image]

#### 2. Use BubbleChart

```
 {aassoc2,bassoc2} = Map[Map@Append[1]]@{aassoc, bassoc};

BubbleChart[{aassoc2,bassoc2}, 
 BubbleSizes -> {.01, .01}, 
 ChartLabels -> Automatic, 
 LabelingFunction -> Callout,
 ChartElementFunction -> "Point", 
 ChartBaseStyle -> PointSize[Medium],
 ChartLegends -> {"A", "B"}, 
 LegendAppearance -> {LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"},
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A minimalistic approach:

```
ListPlot[<|aassoc, bassoc|>,
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRangePadding -> 2]
```

[image]